# What can I do to fix this problem on my Mac?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

When I clicked on the Finder and my username, I open the Applications folder, and there was nothing in it. Somehow I had deleted its contents. However, when I typed Applications in the search in the top right corner of the Mac, it gave me a folder called Applications with all my Adobe products, MAMP and other software in it. So what I did was "copy all" on those applications and dragged them to the empty Applications folder under my username. But then it said it was copying 45,599 items and 13.06 GB of data. I don't think I should have done it this way. It's taking a long time to copy and I don't think I really wanted to duplicate the data.  What can I do

a) to reverse what I did (if I did indeed duplicate all the data)

b) and then get those applications LISTED in the right folder without duplicating the data?

Answer (score 0):

the applications on a mac goes in the folder `/Applications` while the folder you're referring to is `/Users/username/Applications`.

please take some time to understand your system, even though it's trying to keep you away from doing just that. best way to do this is by using the terminal, which can be found using spotlite (or whatever it's called)

in the terminal, use `ls -lhaf` to list the files in a directory, and use `cd [directory name]` to traverse your file system. and the folder one step up (back) in the directory tree is called `..` so use `cd ..` to go up in the tree. to go to the root directory, use `cd /` and to go to the last folder you were in, use `cd -`.

learn where all your files are located on your computer this way. this will reverse the ownership between you and your computer, so that the computer no longer owns you, but instead you own your computer :)

Comment: thank you. I'm trying to figure out how to learn more about my computer.  By the way, would you recommend that I just "delete" all the copied files in /Users/username/Applications.  Based on what you said, that obviously won't have any effect on the files in /Applications, right?

Comment: that solution will only have the desired effect if the folder /Users/username/Applications really was empty when you copied the files in there. just because your finder displayed it as empty doesn't mean it actually _was_ empty. isn't there some undo functionality in the finder? have you tried holding the button with a weird looking cracker on it and pressing `z`?

Comment: by the way, can you tell me where you learn all this stuff about the command line and I will happily read it.

Comment: I tried press command z but it seemed to be copying everything again. I deleted it all and everything still seems to be working. Thanks for your help.  Again, if you do know a good book to read to understand the innerworkings of a Mac, then please let me know. Cheers.

Comment: sorry, i don't have a book i can refer you to. i am myself a firm disbeliever in mac because of the way it shields the user from what's really going on. the commands from the terminal are *nix commands, so most linux commands work fine. this means that if you want to do something in your terminal, search for how to do this in linux, and the same will likely work in your terminal :)